# batch script to extract lines between two specified lines

Tags: batch-file, scripting, extract, lines

I have a text file and would like to extract all the lines between two specified lines using windows batch scripting.

Line1: !FILE_FORMAT=ADS

Line2: !VERSION=1.0

.

.

LineX: 'Parent|Child|IsPrimary|********** (the line starts with ' and is long)

.

.

LineY: !PropertyArray=Cost Center (The lines starts with !)

.

.

LineZ.

I want to extract all the lines between LineX and LineY and output it to another file.

The below code finds the starting line correctly. But it just deletes the line(Line Y) where I want the stop the script and outputs the rest of the file.

The output is from Line X to Line Z without Line Y.

```
@for /f "tokens=1 delims=[]" %%a in ('find /n "'Parent|Child"^<D:\DEV\Test\Cost_Center.txt') do @(
more +%%a D:\DEV\Test\Cost_Center.txt |find /v "!PropertyArray=Cost Center" || goto :eof)>D:\DEV\Test\Cost_Center_Out.txt
```

Comment: Are there any other lines that start with ' or ! ? Do these line numbers change?

Comment: There are quotes inside lines? What do you mean when you say line "is long"?

Answer (score 3):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL 
SET "sourcedir=c:\sourcedir"
SET "destdir=c:\destdir"
for /f "tokens=1 delims=[]" %%a in ('find /n "'Parent|Child"^<"%sourcedir%\Cost_Center.txt" ') do set /a start=%%a
for /f "tokens=1 delims=[]" %%a in ('find /n "!PropertyArray=Cost Center"^<"%sourcedir%\Cost_Center.txt" ') do set /a end=%%a
(
for /f "tokens=1* delims=[]" %%a in ('find /n /v ""^<"%sourcedir%\Cost_Center.txt" ') do (
 IF %%a geq %start% IF %%a leq %end% ECHO(%%b
 )
)>"%destdir%\newfile.txt"
GOTO :EOF
```

Using the approach that you're comfortable with - I've changed the source and destination directories/filenames to suit my system. Not sure whether you want to include your two target lines - it's just a matter of changing `geq` to `gtr` and/or `leq` to `lss` depending on which, if any, you want to exclude.

Might have been easier if you'd included some sample data...

---

edit 20130807T0207Z `ECHO` becomes `ECHO(` to cope with empty lines.

Comment: Thanks. Works great. But I get the line "ECHO is off." at the end of the file.

Comment: I've modified the code - the change is very subtle - `ECHO ` becomes `ECHO(`. This would occur on empty lines, where `%%b` is not set and hence is interpreted as an empty string.

Answer (score 2):

you can do this with sed for Windows:

```
sed "/'Parent|Child|IsPrimary|/,/!PropertyArray=Cost Center/!d" file1 > file2
```

Answer (score 1):

This uses a helper batch file called `findrepl.bat` from - http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=4697

```
type file.txt |findrepl "^'Parent\|Child\|IsPrimary\|" /e:"^!PropertyArray=Cost" |findrepl /v "^!PropertyArray=Cost">newfile.txt
```

The `^` at the start of the terms means it starts in column one.  The `\|` you see is the escaping of the `|` character.

Comment: Thanks. It works. But it also includes the line "!PropertyArray=Cost".

Comment: Try it now. I added a filter to remove that line.