# Batch to copy strings between two tags in XML

Tags: xml, string, batch-file, tags, between

Need to pull out all strings between two XML tags, using a batch script.  I'm only interested in pulling out the strings between `<appSettings>`  and `</appSettings>`.  There are many strings above and below this section; need to disregard all other strings.

I've tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18069790/batch-script-to-extract-lines-between-two-specified-lines) solution, but because my start and end strings contain '`<`', I believe that throws off the code.

Example:

**File1.txt  (read from this file)**

```
::Many lines of code to start with.  ~150 lines
<appSettings>
    <add key="1" value="False" />
    <add key="2" value="False" />
    <add key="3" value="False" />
    <add key="4" value="False" />
    <add key="5" value="False" />
    <add key="6" value="False" />
    <add key="7" value="False" />
    <add key="8" value="False" />
    <add key="9" value="False" />
    <add key="10" value="False" />
    <add key="11" value="False" />
    <add key="12" value="False" />
    <add key="13" value="False" />
    <add key="14" value="False" />
    <add key="15" value="False" />
    <add key="16" value="False" />
    <add key="17" value="False" />
</appSettings>
::Many strings below this ~25 lines
```

**File2.txt** (Create and write to this file)

*This file should be created, and contain all strings between `<appSettings>` and `</appSettings>` from File1.txt

Comment: Does PowerShell count as batch?

Comment: hmm, good question.  It needs to run along with other commands in a pre-existing batch script, so probably best to keep it batch-only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a very simple and fast solution using [REPL.BAT - a hybrid JScript/batch utility](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16735079/1012053) that performs a regex search and replace on stdin and writes the result to stdout. The script is pure script that will run natively on any modern Windows machine from XP onward. Full documentation is embedded within the script.

Assuming REPL.BAT is in your current directory, or better yet, somewhere within your PATH, then:

```
type file1.txt|repl "[\s\S]*?<appSettings>([\s\S]*?)</appSettings>[\s\S]*" $1 m >file2.txt
```

Comment: Thanks dbenham - I stumbled upon your repl.bat before, I'll give it a shot with this command

Answer (score 0):

This solution ought to work so long as the `<appSettings>` tags are on lines by themselves. I've tried to take into account extraneous whitespace (outside the tags). The first argument to the script is the XML file.

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

SET INSIDE_ELT=0
FOR /F "delims=" %%l IN (%~1) DO (
    SET "LINE=%%~l"
    SET "LINE=!LINE:<=__-_!"
    SET "LINE=!LINE:>=_-__!"
    CALL :STRIP !LINE!
    SET "LINE=!_STRIPPED:__-_=<!"
    SET "LINE=!LINE:_-__=>!"
    IF "!LINE!"=="</appSettings>" SET INSIDE_ELT=0
    IF "!INSIDE_ELT!"=="1" @ECHO %%l
    IF "!LINE!"=="<appSettings>" SET INSIDE_ELT=1
)


:STRIP
SET "_STRIPPED=%*"
EXIT /B
```

Comment: Great - looks like it works perfectly!  It ECHO's exactly what's needed.  Now, instead of ECHOing, how would I export this to a new file? >> file2.txt  ?  Also, how would I add the source file (file1.txt) right into this code, to avoid having to run it as an argument?  Much appreciated

Comment: You can pipe the output of the command (or the single echo statement) to a file, like `@ECHO %%l >> file2.txt`. If you wanted to hardcode the name of the input file, replace the `%~1` in the `FOR` statement.

Comment: if file1.txt is not in the same directory as the batch i.e. setup\config files\file1.txt), how would I point there instead?  I've tried using the full path (c:\setup\config files\file1.txt) as well as (setup\config files\file1.txt), with and without quotes to account for the space in the path.

Comment: I worked around the above issue by just copying file1.txt to the root directory.  My next question is, how would I process two separate files, in the same batch script?  Simply pasting the code again (modifying the hard-coded File1.txt to file2.txt in the 2nd instance) just goes in a loop.  Also tried removing the Exit from the first code set, and using GOTO to no avail.  Thoughts?

Comment: Why not just make use of the command-line parameter and invoke the script twice, once per file? It worked just fine for me specifying a file name on the command line.

Comment: ah, good point.  It'd be preferable to keep it all in 1 script, but not a requirement.  In going that route, since I'm piping the output to a file (file2.txt), It'd be overwritten when invoking the script the 2nd time.  I think I can get around this by simply renaming the output file to something else before the 2nd run - but, my 'pilot' batch script (the batch script that is giving the command to run this one with the argument) is exiting before it gets to the rename - or the 2nd run of this script for that matter.  @mojo

Comment: You could also do an append redirect (`>> output.txt`) with the  second invocation.

Comment: This script (exactly as it is here answered, only with >> output.txt added to the echo) is called script.bat.  Here is my 'pilot' script. Lines are separated by pipes.  script file1.txt | ren output.txt output1.txt | script file2.txt | ren output.txt output2.txt.     pilot script ends after the first line.  I would have thought it'd continue, but perhaps the EXIT in script.bat is halting it.  I tried removing the EXIT as well.

Comment: Pipes (`|`) send the output of one command to the input of another. This isn't what you want (e.g. `ren` doesn't read anything from stdin). You want to redirect the output and then execute another command. Perhaps something like `script file1.txt & ren output.txt output1.txt & script file2.txt & ren output.txt output2.txt`. It would be best not to have the `>>output.txt` in the script at all and just redirect the output of the script: `script file1.txt > output1.txt & script file2.txt > output2.txt` It accomplishes the same thing in a better way.

Answer (score 0):

For this task FINDREPL.BAT from Aacini is intuitive, and is also very quick and robust.

Here is the helper batch file called `findrepl.bat` - download from:  https://www.dropbox.com/s/rfdldmcb6vwi9xc/findrepl.bat

Place `findrepl.bat` in the same folder as the batch file or on the path.

```
type file1.txt|findrepl /i "<appSettings>" /e:"</appSettings>" >file2.txt
```