# Extract lines from a text file that are between specific lines and pattern may come multiple times in the file

Tags: batch-file, text-parsing

I am trying to extract lines from a text file that comes between specific lines.  Following is sample input file

```
---------- E:\SCRIPT\SEARCH\TARGET\00_H1.TXT

Test Line1\Bargain1.txt

Test Line2\Bargain1.txt

some text3\Bargain1.txt

Another text line4\Bargain1.txt

---------- E:\SCRIPT\SEARCH\TARGET\00_E1.TXT
Tex1\Bargain1.txt

Text2\Bargain1.txt

Text file2\Bargain1.txt

text file3\Bargain1.txt

---------- E:\SCRIPT\SEARCH\TARGET\00_D1.txt

---------- E:\SCRIPT\SEARCH\TARGET\00_D2.txt

---------- E:\SCRIPT\SEARCH\TARGET\00_H1.TXT

Test For script1\Bargain2.txt

some text 2\Bargain2.txt

Test For script3\Bargain2.txt

Another text line 5\Bargain2.txt

---------- E:\SCRIPT\SEARCH\TARGET\00_E1.TXT

Text1\Bargain2.txt

Text8\Bargain2.txt

Text from another book\Bargain2.txt

text for me\Bargain2.txt

---------- E:\SCRIPT\SEARCH\TARGET\00_D1.txt

TESTFile\Bargain2.txt

Sample\Bargain2.txt

---------- E:\SCRIPT\SEARCH\TARGET\00_D2.txt

SAMPLE2\Bargain2.txt
```

EXPECTED OUTPUT for extracting data between "---------- E:\SCRIPT\SEARCH\TARGET\00_H1.TXT" and "---------- E:\SCRIPT\SEARCH\TARGET\00_E1.TXT" lines is as follows:

```
---------- E:\SCRIPT\SEARCH\TARGET\00_H1.TXT

Test Line1\Bargain1.txt

Test Line2\Bargain1.txt

some text3\Bargain1.txt

Another text line4\Bargain1.txt

---------- E:\SCRIPT\SEARCH\TARGET\00_H1.TXT

Test For script1\Bargain2.txt

some text 2\Bargain2.txt

Test For script3\Bargain2.txt

Another text line 5\Bargain2.txt
```

I have seen someone here before providing a script that could extract data between the two lines but if pattern is repeating again in the file, that is where it gets challenging.

Following is that code:

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL 
SET "sourcedir=C:\Scripts\src"
SET "destdir=C:\Scripts\destination"
for /f "tokens=1 delims=[]" %%a in ('find /n "---------- E:\SCRIPT\SEARCH\TARGET\00_H1"^<"%sourcedir%\txtresult.txt" ') do set /a start=%%a
for /f "tokens=1 delims=[]" %%a in ('find /n "---------- E:\SCRIPT\SEARCH\TARGET\00_E1"^<"%sourcedir%\txtresult.txt" ') do set /a end=%%a
(
for /f "tokens=1* delims=[]" %%a in ('find /n /v ""^<"%sourcedir%\txtresult.txt" ') do (
 IF %%a geq %start% IF %%a lss %end% ECHO(%%b
 )
)

>"%destdir%\Text_Filtered.txt"
```

```
Source: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18069790/batch-script-to-extract-lines-between-two-specified-lines?rq=1
```

Comment: Please - pretty please - consider using a *real* language.  Powerscript, for example: [Parsing Text with PowerShell](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/powershell/parsing-text-with-powershell-1-3/)

Comment: As the output you're wanting to parse is clearly that resulting from a `FIND` command with a file glob as the input, it would probably make more sense if you change that command first or instead. Currently it probably looks something like this `find [options] "string" E:\Script\Search\Target\00_*.txt`. _BTW, the file you've tried to show us as your example cannot have that content because it clearly shows that you have multiple instances of files with the same names in the same directory, and with different content, which cannot happen._

Comment: Input file is created by another script which was looking for specific words with a for loop against multiple files. What I am sharing is just the example. I have modified above query to add the keywords that were searched for to create these files e.g. Bargain1.txt and Bargain2.txt

Comment: You still need to provide genuine data, it is clear from what you've posted that is is not possible to do what you're asking because the file you're parsing cannot ever look like that, unless it's been manually created with fake file names and paths! We can only assist you if you're using genuine files which we could ourselves create in order to replicate your issue.

Comment: Unfortunately due to NDA I could not post the real data. Thank you for your help!